# Where are my SXA items?

Tags: sxa, powershell-extensions

Running 10.2, I followed the SXA installation instructions and installed:

- Powershell Extensions 6.3
- Sitecore Experience Accelerator 10.2.0 rev. 04247

If I go into `/templates`, then SXA stuff is there, and if I insert an item under `/content`, then I get 'Tenant Folder' as an option so that pipeline processor is running, but I'm not seeing any Powershell stuff.  I don't have SXA items under `/system/modules/Powershell/Script Library` and don't get 'Tenant' as an insert option for `/content` or for a 'Tenant Folder' item.

I haven't taken the time to try to deserialize the protobuf files in the SXA package to see what items they contain, but I get this in logs:

```
\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.SXA.DAT, updated item definitions count = 19.  
\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.SXA.DAT, new item definitions count = 7128.  
\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.SXA.DAT, updated shared definitions count = 19.  
\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.SXA.DAT, new shared definitions count = 6129.  
\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.SXA.DAT, updated language definitions count = 19.    
\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.SXA.DAT, new language definitions count = 7128.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Because you are not using supported **SPE** package.

Make sure you downloaded it from [dev.sitecore.net](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator/10x/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator_1020.aspx). Right now package on github is insufficient.

More info in [Sitecore Experience Accelerator compatibility tables](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0180187)

**Explanation**

Starting from **SXA 10.2** - items will be delivered/stored inside dat files (not in SQL).

Every item that has a dependency on other items (SXA scaffolding scripts depend on SPE) need dependency items stored in dat files as well.
If you installed regular package (not IAR enabled) you won't see SXA script library because they cannot be added by composite item provider.

That's why you can add Tenant Folder (because it's a regular template that has no dependency) but you cannot add Tenant or Site (they are scripts added as insert options and their templates come from SPE package).

I already created [PR in SPE](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/commit/9253adb8586feee317b20f51e98ad64541240986) so next releases should contain both versions of package.

Comment: Huh.  So that SPE will make the .dat items show up in content editor?  I figured at least the items would show up unless something was really wrong.  What's the connection between the two?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking about. Btw. to avoid potential problems  in the future install everything from scratch. If you already installed regular package and deployed iar enabled on top of it, I would recommend reinstalling instance (because right now you have items both in SQL and in .dat, which might be an issue during SPE upgrade - leftovers)
If it's impossible head to `/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SXA/SXA - Upgrade/Functions/Upgrade Scripts/Content architecture cleanup` and run it just for SPE paths (lines 189-213). This will remove SQL items.

Comment: Oh, I now see what you mean by dependency items.   It appears that an item from a .dat won't be added to the tree unless it's parent is also from a .dat

Comment: Yup, parent or template :)