# Powershell Reports menu not appearing

Tags: powershell-extensions

We upgraded a Sitecore site from 9.1 to 10.2. After the upgrade we installed the latest SPE. Everything works as expected except the SPE Reports submenu; it doesn't show, even for the admin user.
We tried granting access to the Sitecore Client Authoring but that didn't help.

What debugging steps can we do to find the cause of this issue?

[image]

Comment: Which package did you install? (please share full name from github)

Comment: @AlanPłócieniak Sitecore PowerShell Extension for Sitecore (`Sitecore.PowerShell.Extensions-6.3 - IAR.zip`) from Sitecore Downloads: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator/10x/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator_1020.aspx

Comment: Your question made me think about whether the SPE package version is different between Sitecore downloads (IAR) and github. It seems it is. I installed the one in github (without IAR) and it worked!! Please add your your comment as an answer

Comment: @TarmerM  You will find the same IAR package on github as well. Please see my answer. If you have questions feel free to ask. IAR package could still work but additional work is needed. If you are using SXA you should stick with IAR. You could install IAR and re-run `Content architecture cleanup` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore introduced Items as Resources (**IAR**) in **10.1**

Starting with **10.2** it was also done for **SPE** (because SXA moved to IAR)

You might be wondering why - because it's necessary (SXA has a dependency on SPE).  You can read more about it [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/30375/16)

#### Here is where problems might occur

**SPE** is delivered right now as:

- **SPE-NORMAL** - regular package - items will be stored in SQL - `Sitecore.PowerShell.Extensions-6.3.zip`
- **SPE-IAR** - IAR enabled package - items will be stored as `*.dat` files - `Sitecore.PowerShell.Extensions-6.3-IAR.zip`

If you pick the wrong for your case, you will have problems (missing items, broken SXA scaffolding). It happens because item provider takes items from both sources (SQL, `*.dat`) which might led to unpredictable results.

#### Rules

Here are rules you should follow when upgrading/installing **SPE/SXA** for **10.2+**.

- **`NO SXA`**

  - `FRESH INSTALLATION` - install **SPE-NORMAL** or **SPE-IAR** - IAR is better for future upgrades (no leftovers in SQL) - I recommend it,
  - `UPGRADE` - install **SPE-NORMAL** - installing **SPE-IAR** is possible but you would have to cleanup items from SQL after that. With SXA it's done by upgrade script, you would have to do similar thing.
- **`WITH SXA`** - for **10.2+** **SPE-IAR** is a must

  - `FRESH INSTALLATION` - install **SPE-IAR** before **SXA**,
  - `UPGRADE` - install **SPE-IAR** before you install **SXA**, then after you run SXA upgrade scripts (it will cleanup items for SXA and SPE form SQL so they are consumed from `*.dat` files)

Comment: This client had PowerShell installed before the upgrade mainly for reports without SXA. After the upgrade they wanted to install SXA too.  Installing the IAR only didn't show the SPE Reports menu, only after installing the normal SPE package we were able to open the menu.