# Sitecore 10.2 ARM Template based install on Azure XM Small throws exception Could not load file or assembly Sitecore.Analytics, Version=17.0.0.0

Tags: sxa, installation, packages

Using the walk through [Walkthrough: Deploying a new Sitecore environment to the Microsoft Azure App service](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--deploying-a-new-sitecore-environment-to-the-microsoft-azure-app-service.html) all packages chosen for XM only. However I get this error
[image]

This is not an XM Install, wonder why would this happen. Anyone had this issue please share your suggestions to correct my course please.

Comment: Do you have this `<add key="sxaxm:define" value="sxaxmonly"/>` under `appSettings` in your `web.config`?

Comment: I might be too exited, but this works for me. I have added the config. So Thanks. Can you let me know where in any documentation is this mentioned? But now thought installed SXA is not visible at all. Not in the PowerShell Tools and not even in the Content Editor

Comment: It's not documented as it should happenen automatically during installation. Regarding missing SPE, SXA please make sure you are using correct version of SXA, SPE, more info here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/30759/16

It looks like you installed regular SPE package instead of SPE 6.3 IAR (items as resources).

Answer (score 1):

For **XM** topology.

Please make sure that you have this in your `web.config`

```xml
<appSettings>
    <!-- [...] -->
    <add key="sxaxm:define" value="sxaxmonly"/>
</appSettings>
```

It should be added automatically during SXA installation, not sure why in your case it wasn't.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <appSettings>
        <add patch:instead="*[@key='sxaxm:define']" key="sxaxm:define" value="sxaxconnect" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It doesn't get applied because the transform in the SXA package that tries to insert the `sxaxm:define` key is missing `xdt:Locator="Match(key)"`.