# IAR Items Invisible in Content Tree But Exist

Tags: serialization

I am using Items as Resources (IAR) and have been for weeks now. Now, for some reason I am unable to see the items in the content tree.

[image: Missing item]

You can see in the screenshot that the item is searchable and is even viewable via direct access in content editor, but I am unable to find the item through the content tree. Notice that there is no arrow allowing me to expand "Data Exchange". Again, this was working as expected for a while.

I was able to confirm that all of my items exist by selecting the "Data Exchange" item and searching for an empty string:

[image: Items exist]

The "175 results" are my items. I have tried recycling the app pool, logging out, clearing the cache, viewing DbBrowser.aspx... nothing changes what I see. Additionally, the logs indicate that it loaded the items correctly:

[image: Items imported]

No other errors are present in the logs. Sitecore 10.1

EDIT #1: I also changed my Sitecore.json as it was previously truncating items with long paths. However, this did not make any difference either.

EDIT #2: Rebuilt links database, recycled app. No luck.

Comment: They are not hidden, are they? https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2017/02/24/sitecore-hiding-items-clean-up-the-cluttered-content-tree/

Comment: No. I figured it out and will post the answer Monday. IMO it’s a bug. I had to include the Data Exchange item as well… which is also IAR. Will explain more in answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a moderate deep-dive, this appears to be a bug in the IAR implementation. The short answer is that you need overlap between the database items and IAR items. Long answer below...

The problem is defined like this:

- *sitecore (IAR)*

  - *system (IAR)*

    - **data exchange (database)**

      - *top-level child (IAR)*

        - *many other items (IAR)*

In this configuration, the top-level child does not appear as a child in the content tree. There are two options to get our items to show up in the content tree.

### 1 - Install the top-level child as a database item

It sounds strange (and it is) but you can create a package of an IAR item and then reinstall it and it will then become a database item. If we do this for our top-level child, install it and recycle the app pool, then we now see the content tree acts properly and displays our items.

### 2 - Generate the IAR file with the data exchange item

If we modify our items.json file and include a reference to the data exchange item (i.e. the next-closest database parent) then we also see the proper content tree.

```
{
    "name": "DEF",
    "path": "/sitecore/system/Data Exchange",
    "allowedPushOperations": "createOnly",
    "scope": "SingleItem"
},
```

### Best Solution

The best solution is for this bug to be patched. In the meantime, the best solution appears to be option 2- since the entire point of the IARs is so that you do not have to install a package.

Comment: I was browsing a different issue and I see that this has been discussed previously in an SXA context: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/30371/where-are-my-sxa-items the end result is the same- don't mix IAR and SQL.